# C#-How to update a first row in DataTable based on dictionary values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

For example, I have an DataTable with first row of values as Month, year, name, age
i have dictionary having values of [month mapped to pay_month], [year mapped to pay_year].

I have to update data table month value as pay_month and year value as pay_year], this is for only first row of DataTable.

How i can do this, kindly help.

Comment: where is the data table that you want to update? Give an example of main logic/ snippet here.

Comment: Please take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the [Stack Overflow question checklist by Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dictionary.Add("pay_month", 2);
    dictionary.Add("pay_year", 1);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) 
     {
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];

        row["Month"]=dictionary["pay_month"];
        row["year"]=dictionary["pay_year"];
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Loop through all row in Datatable and find item to update by dictionary key , if that exists then update datarow.

```
foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    foreach(var key in DictionaryObject)
    if(dr[key]!= null) 
    {
        dr[key] = DictionaryObject[key]; 
    }
}
```